# How do I redirect to same page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, confirm

How should I change my javascript code to prevent it link to another page after click cancel on the window confirm()?

Or I should use jQuery to solve this problem?

Please help. Thanks

```js
function checktext() {
  var x = document.forms["myTable"]["id"].value;
  if (isNaN(x)) {
    alert("Please check ID!");
    return false;
  }
}

function myFunction() {
  var check = confirm("Are You Confirm To Submit?");
  if (check == true) { 
      console.log("yes");
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="table_field" id="insert_form" method="post" onsubmit="return checktext()" action="apply.inc.php">
  <hr>
  <h1 class="text-center">Overtime Table</h1>
  <hr>
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Full Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="form-control" name="id[]" type="text" id="id" required></td>
      <td><input class="form-control" name="name[]" type="text" id="name" required></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <b>Send To:</b>
  <select class="form-control" name="options">
    <option value="-----" id="-----" hidden>-----</option>
    <option value="Table_A">Table A</option>
    <option value="Table_B">Table B</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit a form, a `submit` event is called. That event contains some information and actions that are stored in an `SubmitEvent` object. The object is available when you listen for the event through the `onsubmit` attribute, `onsubmit` property or through `addEventListener`.

**I would highly recommend to use `addEventListener`** as the attribute version is just an old technology that does not want to seem to die and has weird side effects that `addEventListener` has not.

When you don't want a form to submit while submitting, call the `preventDefault()` method on the `event` object. That will make sure that your form will not send and not reload the page when you want it to.

```js
var form = document.getElementById('insert_form');

function onSubmit(event) {
  var x = event.target.elements["id"].value;
  if (isNaN(x)) {
    alert("Please check ID!");
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  
  var check = confirm("Are You Confirm To Submit?");
  if (check == true) { 
    console.log("yes");
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}

form.addEventListener('submit', onSubmit);
```

```html
<form name="table_field" id="insert_form" method="post" action="apply.inc.php">
  <hr>
  <h1 class="text-center">Overtime Table</h1>
  <hr>
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Full Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="form-control" name="id[]" type="text" id="id" required></td>
      <td><input class="form-control" name="name[]" type="text" id="name" required></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <b>Send To:</b>
  <select class="form-control" name="options">
    <option value="-----" id="-----" hidden>-----</option>
    <option value="Table_A">Table A</option>
    <option value="Table_B">Table B</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just learned about preventDefault().

Answer (score 3):

You can refresh the page by the following code in your if condition.

```
window.location.reload()
```

OR

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

OR

```
window.location.replace(window.location.href);
```

Comment: @newbird please mark the answer as verified